# Click event on <a> tag inside <span> tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying something simple, i am quite noob in jquery and i don´t know how to make an click event when you click in an a tag that is inside a span tag, this is my code.

```
<span>
    <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="table_id" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
    <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="table_id" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
    <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="table_id" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
    <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="table_id" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
</span>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$("#table_id_paginate > span > a.paginate_button").click(function() {
alert("Handler for .click() called.");});
```

Comment: `$(".paginate_button").click(...)`? Unless you need to worry about scope, just targeting the class `paginate_button` should be fine, right?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console? Do you have the jquery linked to your page?

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: is the span a child of `#table_id_paginate` or a descendant? if it's a decendant rather than a direct child then use `"#table_id_paginate span > a.paginate_button"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup you provided does not have an element with the ID "table_id_paginate". So jQuery is selecting the links because it is looking for `a` elements with the class `paginate_button` who are direct descendants of a `span` that is a direct descendant of an element with that ID.

So if you change your code to how Tim Lewis commented: `$(".paginate_button").click(...)` the code works.

Comment: Good explanation. The id `#table_id_paginate` makes me think it's a `<table>`, and `<span>` is not a valid child of `<table>` so even then... Hard to say without the whole markup eh?

Comment: Thanks! i complicated myself and it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just making this change will make it work, basically you want that any `<a>` tag with `.paginate_button` class should work on click.

```
<script>
$("span > a.paginate_button").click(function() {
alert("Handler for .click() called.");});
</script>
```

**Edit :** 
How to go about these :
Figure out the target element, then keep going up towards the parent and 
that becomes your target.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a.paginate_button").on("click", function () {
     //your code here
})
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).